# Not able to filter data from view for public access user

Tags: xpages

I need to access and filter data from an nsf file for which I made the access public as per instructions : [XPages Public Access Support](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Public_Access_Support)

I am accessing this database from another database.

When I put the view on an xpage whithout filtering the data , everything works fine.
The anonymous user can see the view all the data.

Once I start filtering the data of the view , I get a message : "Notes error: You are not authorized to perform that operation"
The filtering is correct since , when I log into the database , and refresh the xpage , all data is filtered and displayed correctly.

**EDIT**
When I filter the view data with "Filter by column value" , the xpage seems to work.
It doesn't work when I filter the data with "Search in view results"
What can I do ?

Comment: what kind of filtering do you mean exactly? By key? Or do you use the search?

Comment: Show us your code. You are clearly using something that Anonymous can not access

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know are users with public access not allowed to perform full text searches. I don't believe that this restriction can be overridden.

**EDIT:**

You need at least reader access to perform a search in a view.

Comment: Any reason for this as the user is allowed to see all the documents in the view , why can't he see just a selective part of it?
I guess I will have to make a new view , with the search integrated so I can search through the "filter by column value". The only thing I don't like this way is that I have to make another view ....